# How can I get the activations of a LSTM in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I would like to obtain the activations of the three gates of an trained LSTM cell in TensorFlow for a specific input and state. TensorFlow lacks an equivalent functionality to PyTorch's 'hook'. I trained a network to play arcade games. The wohle network works, so no problems regarding the original code.

Code:

```
[...]
core = tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell(512)
[...]
output, state = core(input, state)
I tried:
shape_input_input = tf.shape(input)
shape_input_state = tf.shape(current_state)
lstm_layer = core
lstm_layer_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=shape_input_input)
lstm_layer_state = tf.keras.Input(shape=shape_input_state)
output_sequences, final_memory_state, final_carry_state = lstm_layer(inputs = lstm_layer_input, states = lstm_layer_state) (that doesn't work)
tf.keras.Model(??)
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to retrieve the activations (not the weights) for a given input and state? Thank you!

I tried:

```
output_sequences, final_memory_state, final_carry_state = lstm_layer(input_LSTM_input , input_LSTM_state)
input_gate_output = lstm_layer.cell.input_gate
forget_gate_output = lstm_layer.cell.forget_gate
output_gate_output = lstm_layer.cell.output_gate
activation_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=lstm_layer.input, outputs=[output_sequences, final_memory_state, final_carry_state, input_gate_output, forget_gate_output, cell_gate_output, output_gate_output])
```

I discovered a similar approach for obtaining activations in CNNs, and I was hopeful that it would work for LSTM cells as well, but unfortunately, it doesn't.

Comment: Hi @Sabine To obtain the activations of the input gate, forget gate, and output gate of a trained LSTM cell in TensorFlow, you can create a custom model that extracts these activations during inference.